# Not able to render mail content to html/text format in rails 4.0.8

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

My mailer method given below(customer_mailer.rb)

```
      def X customer, message, cust_mail, email_subject
        subject = email_subject
        mail_ids=cust_mail.to_s.split(",")
        mail :subject => subject || "Your Invoice", :to => mail_ids, :body => message
#mail :subject => subject || "Your Invoice", :to => mail_ids, :body => ERB.new(message).result(binding)

      end
```

my html view (X.html.erb)

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#D6A1A1">

<table width="100%" bgcolor="#D6A1A1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I need to send mail with  content "message" through html format,if i am using commended line of code in my mailer method i can do it,but its alignment,content all are not proper,how can i solve this issue,waiting for your valuable information

Answer (score 0):

Hope your template is in `views/customer_mailer/X.html.erb`